# How to catch pagination element of shopify api with jquery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, iframe, pagination, shopify

[image]

How to enable any of the `pagination` button by clicking on my `ajax` request.

**Scenario**: In my shopify app, I have a checkbox on which I am sending a `ajax` request and in response I want to enable this button.

**Tried**: I have tried some solutions mentioned in stackoverflow but couldn't work.

Here: `window.parent.document` this raise error for `permission denied`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the same code of shopify pagination in the ajax response. So it will take your changed pagination value and enable the pagination buttons.

```
ShopifyApp.ready(function(){
  ShopifyApp.Bar.initialize({
    title: window.mainPageTitle,
    icon: '/icon20x20.png',

    pagination: {
      previous: {href: "/start?page=1"},
      next: {href: "/start?page=3"}
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript you can manually enable the pagination buttons like this:

```
ShopifyApp.Bar.setPagination({
    next: {
      href: "/posts?page=3"
    },
    previous: {
      href: "/posts?page=1"
    }
  });
```

Comment: I think you didn't get my issue, I did the same thing by setting `nil` to next button, but when user click on any checkbox then I want to enable 'next button` with custom `href`. Am I clear to you?